# I want to add different classes on every table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have below markup:

```
<div id="main">
    <table class="test">
       <span>text1</span>
    </table>
    <table  class="test">
       <span>text2</span>
    </table>
    <table  class="test">
       <span>text3</span>
    </table>
    <table class="test">
       <span>text4</span>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to add different class on every table using jquery

Comment: show what you have done. also why can't you add this in the html itself?

Comment: Your html is invalid. You cant have span as direct child of table.

Comment: $("table").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("class" + i);
});

Comment: like `$('table').addClass(function (i) {
    return 'class-' + i;
})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to loop through the tables in your main div and add the class. Here's the core logic

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var classHash = {0 : "test0", 1 : "test1", 2 : "test2", 3: "test3"};
    var table = $("#main > table");
    for(var i=0; i< table.length; i++){
        $(table[i]).addClass(classHash[i]);
    }
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmph5tbj/)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid, but with valid tables this would apply below:

Simply....

```
    $(function () {
        $('#main table').addClass('yourclass');
    });
```

"#main" to identify the div and "table" for all of the tables within that div.

Here is the reference...

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 0):

You can add `class names` which you want to add in a `array` and then add classes to the tables as shown :

```
var arr=["class1","class2","class3",.....];
var count=0;

$('body').find('table').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass(arr[count]);
  count=count + 1;
});
```